# Function in while controller does not work correctly jmeter 5.0

Tags: groovy, jmeter, syntax-error

I am using the function

```
${__groovy(if ((vars.get("body")!="null" && ${counter} < 5)) {return true;} else {return false;};)}
```

to repeat the request if it was not completed.
This part of the plan works, but the execution of the next while controller does not start.
What am I doing wrong? I am not good at programming.

In jmeter console the following error
https://pastebin.com/xhYSFdci

Test case example 
https://pastebin.com/qtuJRpCd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't inline [JMeter Functions and / or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into Groovy scripts, you need to amend your condition to use `vars` shorthand to [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance like:

```
${__groovy(if ((vars.get("body")!="null" && ((vars.get("counter") as int) < 5))) {return true;} else {return false;};)}
```

you also need to cast the variable value to an [Integer](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Integer.html) in order to be able to compare it with `5`.

More information: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/)

Comment: Thanks, but in this case, an error also appears in the console.
https://pastebin.com/BA7GF77b
I decided it by changing the int to Integer.
But the next while loop never started on its own. There are no more errors in the console but the test stops. Why is that?

Comment: Most probably your `counter` variable doesn't exist, double check its value using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/) combination. Also if you're checking current While Controller's iteration you can use `__jm__While Controller__idx` pre-defined variable instead.